# Can the radius of this semicircle be calculated from the given data?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

The semicircle highlighted by the red ellipse has an unspecified radius. Can it be calculated given available data? If not, what additional data is needed?

Note: As stated, all features are symmetrical about the dashed diagonal.

[image]

Comment: If the image is to scale you can measure... But there are all sorts of issue with this picture.

Comment: The scale is in question. I'm aware that the drawing is suboptimal. The charitable interpretation is that things were left out to protect copyright, but my personal opinion is that they're just schmucks.

Comment: two things are problematic: there's no way to work out the thickness of those back "wings" and also, the lines around the semicircle don't look exactly parallel (so it isn't really a **semi**-circle) and nothing allows you to figure out the angle between them

Comment: The lines are not parallel. The angle is for my purposes unknown. If you format your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

*Converting Nick Pavlov's comment into an answer:*

---

Two things are problematic: there's no way to work out the thickness of those back "wings" and also, the lines around the semicircle don't look exactly parallel (so it isn't really a **semi**-circle) and nothing allows you to figure out the angle between them.